# Send ForeignKey Column value in kendo grid to controller on inline edit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

I have been struggling with this for quite sometime. I have a kendo grid which has several dropdownlists inside the grid. I put dropdownlist in the grid using the foreign key column. The grid on inline edit doesn't send the selected dropdownlist value to the controller, it sends the old value. I'm not quite sure what's going wrong, any leads will be very helpful.

Code:

View

```
     @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.App_Client_Mapping)
    .Name("AppAccountInternalGrid")
    .Events(ev => ev.Edit("OnGridEdit"))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {

        columns.Bound(p => p.AccountMappingID).Title("AccountMappingID").Width(130).Hidden(true);

        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.Level1ID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["level1"], "Level1ID", "Level1").Title("Level 1").Width(150).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "Level1Dropdown", data_value_primitive = true });

        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.Level2ID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["level2"], "Level2ID", "Level2").Title("Level 2").Width(150).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "Level2Dropdown" });

        columns.Bound(p => p.ExternalAccount).Title("ExternalAccount").Width(150);
})

         .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
         .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
             .Ajax()
             .PageSize(50)
             .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.AccountMappingID);
                model.Field(p => p.AccountMappingID).Editable(false);                
                model.Field(p => p.Level1ID).DefaultValue(1).Editable(true);
                model.Field(p => p.Level1).Editable(true);
                model.Field(p => p.Level2ID).DefaultValue(0).Editable(true);
                model.Field(p => p.Level2).Editable(true);    
            }


            )

          .Update("EditingInline_Update", "AppAccounts")
          .ServerOperation(false) 
     )



                )
```

Controller:

The grid gets data from this action. The view has other elements along with the grid, so i binded a view model.

```
 public ActionResult AppInternal(int clientid)
    {
     var result = new AppViewModel();

    result.App_Client_Mapping=_unitofwork.AppInternal.Get(clientid);

        var level1 = level1list.Select(x => new App_Client_Mapping
                {

                    Level1ID = x.LevelID,
                    Level1 = x.Level1
                }).ToList();

     var level2 = level2list.Select(x => new App_Client_Mapping
                {

                    Level2ID = x.Level2ID,
                    Level2 = x.Level2

                }).ToList();

          ViewData["level1"] = level1;

                ViewData["level2"] = level2;

    }
     [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
            public ActionResult EditingInline_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, App_Client_Mapping mapping)
        {
           //save the mapping in the database tables

                    return Json(new[] { mapping }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

ViewModel:

AppViewModel:

```
  public class AppMappingViewModel
{
public IEnumerable<App_Client_Mapping> App_Client_Mapping { get; set; }

//other fields

}
```

Auto-generated app_client_mapping class from EF:

```
    public class app_client_mapping
    {
    public int AccountMappingID{get;set;}
    public int Level1ID{get;set;}
    public string Level1{get;set;}
    public int Level2ID{get;set;}
    public string Level2{get;set;}
   public string ExternalAccount{get;set;}
    }
```

When the dataset is passed to the controller. Only the updated value of external local amount (which is a textbox) in the grid is sent. The updated dropdown values aren't sent to the grid. Any ideas as to why this is happening will be a huge help.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your model code your using?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the `.Read` action for your grid ?

Here is how I have my dropdowns inside my grid. I have tried to make it as much a like to your code.

Controller:

```
public IActionResult AppInternal()
{
  ViewData["level1"] = _context.level1list.Select(x => new App_Client_Mapping {
                Level1ID = x.LevelID,
                Level1 = x.Level1
            }); // Do not return a .List()
  // put more dropdowns as required...
  return View();
}

// return the .Read action from your grid
public IActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
  var result = new AppViewModel();
  result.App_Client_Mapping=_unitofwork.AppInternal.Get(clientid);
  return Json(result.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}

// Update
public EditingInline_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, App_Client_Mapping mapping)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // update db with the Level1ID from your dropdown
    }
    // Return the updated product. Also return any validation errors.
    return Json(new[] { mapping }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

View:

```
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.Level1ID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["level1"], "Level1ID", "Level1").Title("Level 1").Width(150); // Don't need to put HtmlAttributes.

// The .Read Action should be
.Read(read => read.Action("Read", "AppAccounts")
```

Foreign Key EditorTemplate:

```
@model object

@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m)
    .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])
    .ValuePrimitive(true)
)
```

There is some code example here: [MVC Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/foreignkeycolumn)